# my app is not working for my new iOS 9 device?

Tags: xcode

My iOS app is not working in the new version of iOS 9 device.It worked perfectly for my older versions .I am using iPhone 6 and the Xcode doesn't provide the app to be run properly after the new update of Xcode. can anyone suggest any solutions?

Comment: You'll have to provide a lot more detail about what's going wrong. Are there error messages you get when you try to run it? What does "Xcode doesn't provide the app to be run properly" mean?

Comment: This too broad . Its like asking help me my car not starting. You need to tell what exacttly happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to run because of the new update in *Xcode*. follow these steps:
open Xcode and click on the target on the left side of your project.
click the info button and custom iOS target properties.Try adding the required support for your app in custom targets.Hope that works for you.